# Is there a uniformly continuous function whose derivative is merely pointwise continuous?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Does there exist a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is uniformly continuous, and whose derivative exists everywhere, and whose derivative is continuous, but not uniformly continuous over the entire real line?

Comment: Yes, see for instance $\frac1x\sin(x^3)$.

Comment: Or just $x^{4/3}/(1+x^2)$.

Comment: @GregMartin From WA I get that the derivative of $\frac{x^{4/3}}{(1+x^2)}$ is $-\frac23 \sqrt[3]x\frac{x^2-2}{(1+x^2)^2}$, which is uniformly contiuous because it's in $C^0_0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I thought that $\sqrt[3]x$ was not uniformly continuous near $0$ because of its unbounded derivative, but I guess that implication doesn't work for bounded domains.

Comment: @GregMartin Remember Heine-Cantor ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any bounded continuous function. Then an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous so uniformly continuous. So $F$ works as long as $f$ isn’t uniformly continuous: for instance, $f(x)=\sin(x\cos{x})$ or $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$.